# How to return a value in an int function when it contains scopes?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that converts a number written in words to numbers.. (e.g in(sixty-four) -> out(64)) with some exceptions of course. well I struggle in this part of code. I don't know what to put as a return value..

```
int tys(string x) {
    int a=0,n,i;
    string sum;
    for (auto &c: x) {
        if (isalpha(c)) c=tolower(c);
        for (i=0;i<x.size()+1;++i) {
            if (x[i]=='-') {
                for (a=i-2;a<i;++a) {
                    sum += x[a];
                    if (sum=="ty") {
                        i=i-3;
                        for (a=0;a<i;++a) sum+=x[a];
                        n=first_digits(sum)*10;
                        sum=' ';
                        a=i+4;
                        while (a<x.size()) {
                            ++a;
                            sum+=x[a];
                            if (a==x.size()) {
                                n+=first_digits(sum);
                                return n;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (i==x.size()){
                for (a=i-1;a<i+1;++a) {
                    sum += x[a];
                    if (sum=="ty") {
                        sum=' ';
                        while (a <x.size()-3) {
                            ++a;
                            sum += x[a];
                            if (a==x.size()-3) {
                                n = first_digits(sum) * 10;
                                return n;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

don't mind the `first_digits` because it's an int function that works already which gives the numbers from 0-20

Comment: Maybe you could return the converted number?

Comment: Your two `return n;` statements seem to do what you want! All you need to do is to change the `return true;` line (which will convert `true` to `1`) to something that you want to return in case of error: maybe `return 0;` or `return MIN_INT;`?

Comment: @AdrianMole 0 Returning 0 won't be good if the string was "0" and was supposed to return 0 after converting.

Comment: @AdrianMole My bad, your solutions seems fine, if the return value is checked after the function is used. For example, if the function returned 0 and the first letter of the string is not '0', then there really was an error.

Comment: @VoidChips Personally, I would prefer the `MIN_INT` return value, as that is less likely to be used as an *actual* value. But it's the same problem as with standard functions like `atoi()`, I guess.

Comment: Is it `zero` or `nought` for `0`?  Either way, the spelled version (the input) doesn't begin with `0`.

Comment: Could you describe in words what this function is supposed to return? Carefully written specs can make questions like "what to put as the return value" trivial. Forget the code for a moment and specify what this function is supposed to do. What is the input? What is the output?

Comment: A widely used solution for this kind of interface design problems is using two outputs. One way would be to return the success status (true==success, false==failure) and write the result value to a variable referenced by a pointer parameter. That way you do not need a special magic number value within the return value range.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks for the first comment.. now i understand what the last `return` value means.. i jst was confused.. maybe it's simple but m still learning (aka newbie haha).. well thanks again and thank y'all too for your comments.. may y'all have a good day